# How to get public posts for particular location using LAT Long

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Need retrive the posts for particular location using graph api in facebook. At present I am using the below URL to find public posts, parameters are access token, lat, long and buffer distance, but this url returns the all the posts irrespective of lat long and buffer distance https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=lunch&type=post&center=17,78&distance=100&access_token=xxxx

Please suggest me if any options available in graph api to fetch the post or messages for particular location